# Getting Resources Exceeded or Bad Code Error in Reportlab while generating PDF Report

Tags: python, pdf, report, reportlab

The reports are being generated fine until I suddenly start getting this error, where I get that **File can't be opened or Resources Exceeded** while generating many reports. Not able to find the root cause of the issue.

We are using multiple inline images in the pdf report and the error points that the particular file can't be opened. Can anyone help in resolving this?

```
2023-08-20 20:40 +00:00: [2023-08-20 20:40:30,796] ERROR in app: Exception on /reports/kelvinDevice [POST]
2023-08-20 20:40 +00:00: Traceback (most recent call last):
2023-08-20 20:40 +00:00:   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/reportlab/lib/utils.py", line 523, in open_for_read
2023-08-20 20:40 +00:00:     return open_for_read_by_name(name,mode)
2023-08-20 20:40 +00:00:   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/reportlab/lib/utils.py", line 463, in open_for_read_by_name
2023-08-20 20:40 +00:00:     return open(name,mode)
2023-08-20 20:40 +00:00:   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/reportlab/lib/rl_safe_eval.py", line 880, in __call__
2023-08-20 20:40 +00:00:     raise BadCode('missing global %s' % self.__name__)
2023-08-20 20:40 +00:00: reportlab.lib.rl_safe_eval.BadCode: missing global open
2023-08-20 20:40 +00:00: 
2023-08-20 20:40 +00:00: During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
2023-08-20 20:40 +00:00: 
2023-08-20 20:40 +00:00: Traceback (most recent call last):
2023-08-20 20:40 +00:00:   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/reportlab/lib/utils.py", line 530, in open_for_read
2023-08-20 20:40 +00:00:     return BytesIO((datareader if name[:5].lower()=='data:' else rlUrlRead)(name))
2023-08-20 20:40 +00:00:   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/reportlab/lib/utils.py", line 476, in rlUrlRead
2023-08-20 20:40 +00:00:     return urlopen(name).read()
2023-08-20 20:40 +00:00:   File "/usr/lib/python3.10/urllib/request.py", line 216, in urlopen
2023-08-20 20:40 +00:00:     return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
2023-08-20 20:40 +00:00:   File "/usr/lib/python3.10/urllib/request.py", line 503, in open
2023-08-20 20:40 +00:00:     req = Request(fullurl, data)
2023-08-20 20:40 +00:00:   File "/usr/lib/python3.10/urllib/request.py", line 322, in __init__
2023-08-20 20:40 +00:00:     self.full_url = url
2023-08-20 20:40 +00:00:   File "/usr/lib/python3.10/urllib/request.py", line 348, in full_url
2023-08-20 20:40 +00:00:     self._parse()
2023-08-20 20:40 +00:00:   File "/usr/lib/python3.10/urllib/request.py", line 377, in _parse
2023-08-20 20:40 +00:00:     raise ValueError("unknown url type: %r" % self.full_url)
2023-08-20 20:40 +00:00: ValueError: unknown url type: '/home/ubuntu/apps/pdf-reports/Temperature.png'
2023-08-20 20:40 +00:00: 
2023-08-20 20:40 +00:00: During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
2023-08-20 20:40 +00:00: 
2023-08-20 20:40 +00:00: Traceback (most recent call last):
2023-08-20 20:40 +00:00:   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/reportlab/lib/utils.py", line 643, in __init__
2023-08-20 20:40 +00:00:     fp = open_for_read(fileName,'b')
2023-08-20 20:40 +00:00:   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/reportlab/lib/utils.py", line 532, in open_for_read
2023-08-20 20:40 +00:00:     raise IOError('Cannot open resource "%s"' % name)
2023-08-20 20:40 +00:00: OSError: Cannot open resource "/home/ubuntu/apps/pdf-reports/Temperature.png"
2023-08-20 20:40 +00:00: 
2023-08-20 20:40 +00:00: During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
2023-08-20 20:40 +00:00: 
2023-08-20 20:40 +00:00: Traceback (most recent call last):
2023-08-20 20:40 +00:00:   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/reportlab/platypus/paraparser.py", line 3215, in parse
2023-08-20 20:40 +00:00:     self.feed(text)
2023-08-20 20:40 +00:00:   File "/usr/lib/python3.10/html/parser.py", line 110, in feed
2023-08-20 20:40 +00:00:     self.goahead(0)
2023-08-20 20:40 +00:00:   File "/usr/lib/python3.10/html/parser.py", line 170, in goahead
2023-08-20 20:40 +00:00:     k = self.parse_starttag(i)
2023-08-20 20:40 +00:00:   File "/usr/lib/python3.10/html/parser.py", line 342, in parse_starttag
2023-08-20 20:40 +00:00:     self.handle_startendtag(tag, attrs)
2023-08-20 20:40 +00:00:   File "/usr/lib/python3.10/html/parser.py", line 427, in handle_startendtag
2023-08-20 20:40 +00:00:     self.handle_endtag(tag)
2023-08-20 20:40 +00:00:   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/reportlab/platypus/paraparser.py", line 3251, in handle_endtag
2023-08-20 20:40 +00:00:     end()
2023-08-20 20:40 +00:00:   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/reportlab/platypus/paraparser.py", line 2718, in end_img
2023-08-20 20:40 +00:00:     defn.image = ImageReader(defn.src)
2023-08-20 20:40 +00:00:   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/reportlab/lib/utils.py", line 655, in __init__
2023-08-20 20:40 +00:00:     annotateException('\nfileName=%r identity=%s'%(fileName,self.identity()))
2023-08-20 20:40 +00:00:   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/reportlab/lib/utils.py", line 1176, in annotateException
2023-08-20 20:40 +00:00:     rl_reraise(t,t(sep.join((_ for _ in (msg,str(v),postMsg) if _))),b)
2023-08-20 20:40 +00:00:   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/reportlab/lib/utils.py", line 138, in rl_reraise
2023-08-20 20:40 +00:00:     raise v.with_traceback(b)
2023-08-20 20:40 +00:00:   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/reportlab/lib/utils.py", line 643, in __init__
2023-08-20 20:40 +00:00:     fp = open_for_read(fileName,'b')
2023-08-20 20:40 +00:00:   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/reportlab/lib/utils.py", line 532, in open_for_read
2023-08-20 20:40 +00:00:     raise IOError('Cannot open resource "%s"' % name)
2023-08-20 20:40 +00:00: OSError: 
2023-08-20 20:40 +00:00: fileName='/home/ubuntu/apps/pdf-reports/Temperature.png' identity=[ImageReader@0x7f73f82c39a0 filename='/home/ubuntu/apps/pdf-reports/Temperature.png'] Cannot open resource "/home/ubuntu/apps/pdf-reports/Temperature.png"
2023-08-20 20:40 +00:00: 
2023-08-20 20:40 +00:00: During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
2023-08-20 20:40 +00:00: 
2023-08-20 20:40 +00:00: Traceback (most recent call last):
2023-08-20 20:40 +00:00:   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 2525, in wsgi_app
2023-08-20 20:40 +00:00:     response = self.full_dispatch_request()
2023-08-20 20:40 +00:00:   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1822, in full_dispatch_request
2023-08-20 20:40 +00:00:     rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
2023-08-20 20:40 +00:00:   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1820, in full_dispatch_request
2023-08-20 20:40 +00:00:     rv = self.dispatch_request()
2023-08-20 20:40 +00:00:   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1796, in dispatch_request
2023-08-20 20:40 +00:00:     return self.ensure_sync(self.view_functions[rule.endpoint])(**view_args)
2023-08-20 20:40 +00:00:   File "/home/ubuntu/apps/pdf-reports/server.py", line 85, in generateKelvinDevice2Report
2023-08-20 20:40 +00:00:     pdfReport = newKelvinDeviceReport.run(reportData)
2023-08-20 20:40 +00:00:   File "/home/ubuntu/apps/pdf-reports/newKelvinDeviceReport.py", line 1167, in run
2023-08-20 20:40 +00:00:     elements.extend(getEventsandPingsTable(reportData,units))
2023-08-20 20:40 +00:00:   File "/home/ubuntu/apps/pdf-reports/newKelvinDeviceReport.py", line 963, in getEventsandPingsTable
2023-08-20 20:40 +00:00:     eventsText = Paragraph('''
2023-08-20 20:40 +00:00:   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/reportlab/platypus/paragraph.py", line 1800, in __init__
2023-08-20 20:40 +00:00:     self._setup(text, style, bulletText or getattr(style,'bulletText',None), frags, cleanBlockQuotedText)
2023-08-20 20:40 +00:00:   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/reportlab/platypus/paragraph.py", line 1821, in _setup
2023-08-20 20:40 +00:00:     style, frags, bulletTextFrags = _parser.parse(text,style)
2023-08-20 20:40 +00:00:   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/reportlab/platypus/paraparser.py", line 3217, in parse
2023-08-20 20:40 +00:00:     annotateException('\nparagraph text %s caused exception' % ascii(text))
2023-08-20 20:40 +00:00:   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/reportlab/lib/utils.py", line 1176, in annotateException
2023-08-20 20:40 +00:00:     rl_reraise(t,t(sep.join((_ for _ in (msg,str(v),postMsg) if _))),b)
2023-08-20 20:40 +00:00:   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/reportlab/lib/utils.py", line 138, in rl_reraise
2023-08-20 20:40 +00:00:     raise v.with_traceback(b)
2023-08-20 20:40 +00:00:   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/reportlab/platypus/paraparser.py", line 3215, in parse
2023-08-20 20:40 +00:00:     self.feed(text)
2023-08-20 20:40 +00:00:   File "/usr/lib/python3.10/html/parser.py", line 110, in feed
2023-08-20 20:40 +00:00:     self.goahead(0)
2023-08-20 20:40 +00:00:   File "/usr/lib/python3.10/html/parser.py", line 170, in goahead
2023-08-20 20:40 +00:00:     k = self.parse_starttag(i)
2023-08-20 20:40 +00:00:   File "/usr/lib/python3.10/html/parser.py", line 342, in parse_starttag
2023-08-20 20:40 +00:00:     self.handle_startendtag(tag, attrs)
2023-08-20 20:40 +00:00:   File "/usr/lib/python3.10/html/parser.py", line 427, in handle_startendtag
2023-08-20 20:40 +00:00:     self.handle_endtag(tag)
2023-08-20 20:40 +00:00:   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/reportlab/platypus/paraparser.py", line 3251, in handle_endtag
2023-08-20 20:40 +00:00:     end()
2023-08-20 20:40 +00:00:   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/reportlab/platypus/paraparser.py", line 2718, in end_img
2023-08-20 20:40 +00:00:     defn.image = ImageReader(defn.src)
2023-08-20 20:40 +00:00:   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/reportlab/lib/utils.py", line 655, in __init__
2023-08-20 20:40 +00:00:     annotateException('\nfileName=%r identity=%s'%(fileName,self.identity()))
2023-08-20 20:40 +00:00:   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/reportlab/lib/utils.py", line 1176, in annotateException
2023-08-20 20:40 +00:00:     rl_reraise(t,t(sep.join((_ for _ in (msg,str(v),postMsg) if _))),b)
2023-08-20 20:40 +00:00:   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/reportlab/lib/utils.py", line 138, in rl_reraise
2023-08-20 20:40 +00:00:     raise v.with_traceback(b)
2023-08-20 20:40 +00:00:   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/reportlab/lib/utils.py", line 643, in __init__
2023-08-20 20:40 +00:00:     fp = open_for_read(fileName,'b')
2023-08-20 20:40 +00:00:   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/reportlab/lib/utils.py", line 532, in open_for_read
2023-08-20 20:40 +00:00:     raise IOError('Cannot open resource "%s"' % name)
2023-08-20 20:40 +00:00: OSError: 
2023-08-20 20:40 +00:00: paragraph text '<para> <b><font size="8">Event Types</font></b> <img src=/home/ubuntu/apps/pdf-reports/Temperature.png width = "16" height="16" valign="middle"/>: <font size="8">Temperature</font> <img src=/home/ubuntu/apps/pdf-reports/Light.png width = "16" height="16" valign="middle"/>: <font size="8">Light</font> <img src=/home/ubuntu/apps/pdf-reports/Shock.png width = "16" height="16" valign="middle"/>: <font size="8">Shock</font> <img src=/home/ubuntu/apps/pdf-reports/Battery.png width = "16" height="16" valign="middle"/>: <font size="8">Battery</font> <img src=/home/ubuntu/apps/pdf-reports/EnteredGeofence.png width = "16" height="16" valign="middle"/>: <font size="8">Entered Geofence</font> <img src=/home/ubuntu/apps/pdf-reports/ExitedGeofence.png width = "16" height="16" valign="middle"/>: <font size="8">Exited Geofence</font> </para>' caused exception 
2023-08-20 20:40 +00:00: fileName='/home/ubuntu/apps/pdf-reports/Temperature.png' identity=[ImageReader@0x7f73f82c39a0 filename='/home/ubuntu/apps/pdf-reports/Temperature.png'] Cannot open resource "/home/ubuntu/apps/pdf-reports/Temperature.png"
2023-08-20 20:40 +00:00: 127.0.0.1 - - [20/Aug/2023 20:40:30] "POST /reports/kelvinDevice HTTP/1.1" 500 -
2023-08-20 20:40 +00:00: [2023-08-20 20:40:30,914] ERROR in app: Exception on /reports/kelvinDevice [POST]
2023-08-20 20:40 +00:00: Traceback (most recent call last):
2023-08-20 20:40 +00:00:   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/reportlab/lib/utils.py", line 523, in open_for_read
2023-08-20 20:40 +00:00:     return open_for_read_by_name(name,mode)
2023-08-20 20:40 +00:00:   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/reportlab/lib/utils.py", line 463, in open_for_read_by_name
2023-08-20 20:40 +00:00:     return open(name,mode)
2023-08-20 20:40 +00:00:   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/reportlab/lib/rl_safe_eval.py", line 880, in __call__
2023-08-20 20:40 +00:00:     raise BadCode('missing global %s' % self.__name__)
2023-08-20 20:40 +00:00: reportlab.lib.rl_safe_eval.BadCode: missing global open
2023-08-20 20:40 +00:00: 
2023-08-20 20:40 +00:00: During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
2023-08-20 20:40 +00:00: 
2023-08-20 20:40 +00:00: Traceback (most recent call last):
2023-08-20 20:40 +00:00:   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/reportlab/lib/utils.py", line 530, in open_for_read
2023-08-20 20:40 +00:00:     return BytesIO((datareader if name[:5].lower()=='data:' else rlUrlRead)(name))
2023-08-20 20:40 +00:00:   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/reportlab/lib/utils.py", line 476, in rlUrlRead
2023-08-20 20:40 +00:00:     return urlopen(name).read()
2023-08-20 20:40 +00:00:   File "/usr/lib/python3.10/urllib/request.py", line 216, in urlopen
2023-08-20 20:40 +00:00:     return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
2023-08-20 20:40 +00:00:   File "/usr/lib/python3.10/urllib/request.py", line 503, in open
2023-08-20 20:40 +00:00:     req = Request(fullurl, data)
2023-08-20 20:40 +00:00:   File "/usr/lib/python3.10/urllib/request.py", line 322, in __init__
2023-08-20 20:40 +00:00:     self.full_url = url
2023-08-20 20:40 +00:00:   File "/usr/lib/python3.10/urllib/request.py", line 348, in full_url
2023-08-20 20:40 +00:00:     self._parse()
2023-08-20 20:40 +00:00:   File "/usr/lib/python3.10/urllib/request.py", line 377, in _parse
2023-08-20 20:40 +00:00:     raise ValueError("unknown url type: %r" % self.full_url)
2023-08-20 20:40 +00:00: ValueError: unknown url type: '/home/ubuntu/apps/pdf-reports/Temperature.png'
```